# Flattening nested array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a horrible looking array which looks like this:

EDIT:

```
array = [
    {
        Letters: [{ Letter: 'A' }, { Letter: 'B' }, { Letter: 'C' }],
        Numbers: [{ Number: '1' }, { Number: '2' }, { Number: '3' }]
    },
    null,
    {
        Letters: [{ Letter: 'D' }, { Letter: 'E' }, { Letter: 'F' }, { Letter: 'G' }, { Letter: 'H' }],
        Numbers: [{ Number: '4' }, { Number: '5' }, { Number: '6' }, { Number: '7' }]
    }
];
```

And want the array to look like this:

```
flattenedArray = [a,b,c,1,2,3,d,e,f,g,h,4,5,6,7]
```

Unfortunately I cannot change the original formatting because that is the form received when merging two API responses that I am getting.

I have tried using:

```
var flattenedArray = [].concat.apply([], array);
```

But it just presents the array in the same format it was entered in.

I was wondering if anybody had any advice?

EDIT:
I have tried implementing the suggestions given - thank you so much for your help. It seems it is a problem with the format of the list - unfortunately using the chrome console which is in a 'tree' format I cannot see the direct structure of the array output.

Thank you for all your help!
EDIT 2: See above for the actual array, thank you for showing me how to see this!

Comment: That's not exactly valid JS array syntax. Was this just a misrepresentation in your question, or is it actually a string you are receiving that looks exactly like this?

Comment: I'm not sure what the string exactly looks like, it is how I interpretted it looking from the developer tools on chrome. I can't figure out how to stop it presenting the information as a tree but it looks more like:

Comment: Then please show us ([edit] it into your question) the output that `console.log(JSON.stringify(array))` generates. Getting a tree view suggests that you are *not* having a plain string

Comment: That is a really useful command to know, thank you! I have updated it with the actual array which looks horrendous.

Comment: Oh well, that's actually not just a nested array but a nested array of objects. Which invalidates all the answers :-(

Comment: Oh dear. Hopefully the other answers will be useful for somebody and you have helped me realise what the actual problem is - one step closer to the solution! :D

Comment: @jess, now you have to treat the objects as well as the arrays. What do you want with `null`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit for the new request of nested arrays/objects** and the flattening, you could use a combined approach with testing for the type of an element.

```js
var array = [{ Letters: [{ Letter: 'A' }, { Letter: 'B' }, { Letter: 'C' }], Numbers: [{ Number: '1' }, { Number: '2' }, { Number: '3' }] }, null, { Letters: [{ Letter: 'D' }, { Letter: 'E' }, { Letter: 'F' }, { Letter: 'G' }, { Letter: 'H' }], Numbers: [{ Number: '4' }, { Number: '5' }, { Number: '6' }, { Number: '7' }] }],
    result = array.reduce(function iter(r, a) {
        if (a === null) {
            return r;
        }
        if (Array.isArray(a)) {
            return a.reduce(iter, r);
        }
        if (typeof a === 'object') {
            return Object.keys(a).map(k => a[k]).reduce(iter, r);
        }
        return r.concat(a);
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Old request and the immortal question how to flat a nested array.

```js
var flat = (r, a) => Array.isArray(a) ? a.reduce(flat, r) : r.concat(a),
    inputArray = array = [[['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3]], [], [['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], [4, 5, 6, 7]]],
    outputArray = inputArray.reduce(flat, []);

console.log(outputArray);
```

Comment: Just tested it out and it works a charm - thank you for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 9):

If you have `lodash`, you can use:

```
_.flattenDeep(array)
```

You can also checkout [their source code](https://github.com/lodash/lodash) for ides on how to implement yourself if you prefer.

Answer (score 8):

You can create recursive function using `forEach()` that will return new array.

```js
var array = [[['a','b','c'],[1,2,3]],[],[['d','e','f','g','h'],[4,5,6,7]]]
function flat(data) {
  var r = []
  data.forEach(e => Array.isArray(e) ? r = r.concat(flat(e)) : r.push(e));
  return r;
}

console.log(flat(array))
```

You can also use `reduce()` instead of `forEach()`

```js
var array = [[['a','b','c'],[1,2,3]],[],[['d','e','f','g','h'],[4,5,6,7]]]

function flat(data) {
  return data.reduce((r, e) => Array.isArray(e) ? r = r.concat(flat(e)) : r.push(e) && r, [])
}

console.log(flat(array))
```

As **@Bergi** suggested you can use `reduce()` like this.

```
data.reduce((r, e) => r.concat(Array.isArray(e) ? flat(e) : [e]), [])
```

Comment: `&& r` will kill readability. I'm sure many people will not understand purpose of it. I'd suggest splitting code into 2 lines and using `return r` instead

Comment: s/can/should/ use `reduce`. If you want imperative iteration, use a `for…of` loop instead of `forEach` with an arrow function.

Comment: Btw, in the case of `concat` you don't need to reassign `r`. Better just use `(r, e) => r.concat(Array.isArray(e) ? flat(e) : [e])` as the reducer.

Comment: @Bergi Wow that is great, just why brackets on `: [e]` how about `data.reduce((r, e) => r.concat(Array.isArray(e) ? flat(e) : e), [])`?

Comment: Because only arrays should be passed to `concat`. Plain values kinda work as well, but concat always has to check whether they are spreadable like arrays (which since ES6 is also not exactly the same any more)

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [flatten](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#flatten) function in [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com).

```
  R.flatten([1, 2, [3, 4], 5, [6, [7, 8, [9, [10, 11], 12]]]]);
    //=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Comment: ,, you are obsessed by ramda .

Answer (score 2):

It's nice to use a recursive function for such cases:

```js
arr = [[['a','b','c'],[1,2,3]],[],[['d','e','f','g','h'],[4,5,6,7]]];

function flatten(arr) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
       result = result.concat(Array.isArray(arr[i])? flatten(arr[i]) : [arr[i]]);
    }
    return result;
}
console.log(flatten(arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Array format is not correct, you are missing `commas(,)`. This is correct array.

`var array = [[['a','b','c'],[1,2,3]],[],[['d','e','f','g','h'],[4,5,6,7]]];`

```js
var array = [[['a','b','c'],[1,2,3]],[],[['d','e','f','g','h'],[4,5,6,7]]];
var result = flatten(array);
    
function flatten(array) {
    var flat = [];
    if(array !== undefined){
    var flat = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
          if (arguments[i] instanceof Array) {
            flat = flat.concat(flatten.apply(null, arguments[i]));
          } else {
            flat.push(arguments[i]);
          }
        }
      }
    return flat;
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I believe this code flattens just one level deep; for deeper flattening, you would need to run this recursively. Or use lodash, as I suggested ;)

Answer (score 1):

No one thought of splicing in-place?

```
function flatten(array){
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i] instanceof Array){
            array.splice.apply(array,[i,1].concat(array[i]));
            i--;
        }
    };
    return array;
}
```

One iteration, no recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Implement flatten function using recursion and spread operator.

```js
const a = [1,[2,[3,4],[5]],6];
const flatten = (arr) => {
    const res = []
    for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        if(!Array.isArray(arr[i])) res.push(arr[i]);
        else res.push(...flatten(arr[i]));
    }
    return res;
}
console.log(flatten(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function steamrollArray(arr) {
  var tmp = [];
  arr.forEach(function(val){
    if(Array.isArray(val))
      tmp = tmp.concat(steamrollArray(val));
    else
      tmp.push(val);
  });

  console.log(tmp);
  return tmp;
}

steamrollArray([1, [2], [3, [[4]]]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = [1,2,[3,4]]

/* let newarr = arr.flat(); */

let newarr = Object.values(arr);
let arr2 = []
for(let val of Object.values(arr)) {
         if(!Array.isArray(val)){
     console.log(val)
     arr2.push(val)
     }    
           for ( let val2 of Object.values(val)){
             arr2.push(val2)
           }
}
console.log(arr2)
```